# PHP- Adding a dynamic prefix to array values

Tags: php

Using Xpath, I'm extracting some data from an HTML page. I've the below portion in my code:

```
 echo '<ol type="A">';    
 foreach ($options as $option) {
 echo '<li>'.$option->nodeValue.'</li>';
 }
echo '</ol>';
```

Result is

- A. some text
- B. some other text
- C. a different text
- D. yet another text

I want to manually copy the output to a text file. When I do that, the prefixes (A., B.,C,D.) are not copied from browser to text file. So I want to add the prefixes A,B,C,D to my $option->nodeValue inside the foreach loop (always 4 members in the array)- instead of using li tag. How can I do that? (or is there a way to simple copy from browser with the li tag output :) )

Comment: Please show a sample of the result you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu mean like this?

```
$letters=['A','B','C','D'];
echo '<ol type="A">';    
 foreach ($options as $index=>$option) {
 echo '<li>'.$letters[$index] . " " . $option->nodeValue.'</li>';
 }
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: yes, this was exactly what I wanted. thanks